# Unable to parse package2-descriptor.json: invalid attribute 'versionNumber'

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package, cli

I am trying to make a version of my package but it fails every time.

I am able to create a scratch org, install package dependencies, and push my source code successfully. But when I go to create a version of the package, I get the following error:

```
ERROR running force:package:version:create:  Unable to parse package2-descriptor.json: invalid attribute 'versionNumber'
```

I canot find package2-description.json in my directory structure and don't know what info is missing.

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
{
  "path": "force-app",
  "default": true,
  "package": "nllg-base",
  "versionName": "Fall 2019",
  "versionNumber": "1.0.0.NEXT",
  "dependencies": [
      {
          "package": "advpm",
          "versionNumber": "1.86.0.LATEST"
      },
      {
          "package": "pdpamm",
          "versionNumber": "1.55.0.LATEST"
      }
    ]
  }
 ],
 "namespace": "",
 "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
 "sourceApiVersion": "46.0",
 "packageAliases": {
   "nllg-base" : "0HoXXXXXXXXX",
   "advpm": "04tXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   "pdpamm": "04tXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  }
}
```

Using the following command

```
sfdx force:package:version:create -w 10 -v alias -p nllg-base -k key
```

Comment: Looks to be related a similar issue: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A00000159kJQAQ. Currently searching for a work-around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the error message was misleading. A Salesforce developer helped me understand that the tooling api has a slightly different set of configurations, and that is why the package2-description.json was mentioned, even thought it has nothing to do with my sfdx project.

Second "If you are going to specify a dependent package by the 04t ID, then do not also use the versionNumber attribute.
The 04t value point at a specific version already. You should only specify the versionNumber attribute when you are referencing a 0Ho value (which will also be from your specific dev hub) and then you can request a specific version since your dev hub has the version info" [reference](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000Lg5U&fId=0D53A00004aYIGD&s1oid=00D300000000iTz&s1nid=0DB30000000072L&emkind=chatterCommentNotification&s1uid=0053A00000ECR5e&emtm=1570201359970&fromEmail=1&s1ext=0)